# How do I catch an error in @Body annotation in Micronaut so that I can throw a structured execption

Tags: micronaut

I want to return standardized exceptions from my Micronaut application and I can achieve this in most cases through a combination of  try - catch - exception in the controller and a @Error trap for ConstraintViolationException.
However, if the @Body fails to create the object in the request then I get a HttpClientResponseException which I can't seem to trap and reformat